# Python function to write byte array to all jpg files in the folder it is

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

I have a code that writes all the bytes of all the .jpg files in a folder but it's not working, after running it just filling itself with the bytes and not the .jpg files.

**code:**

```
import os

def main():
    path = __file__ #name of file = file.py
    path = path.replace('file.py', '') # replace the name of file to get folder path
    your_path = path #path of imgs and python file
    files = os.listdir(your_path)
    keyword = "*.jpg"
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(your_path, file)):
            f = open(os.path.join(your_path, file),'wb')
            for x in f:
                if keyword in x:
                    x = b'\0'  #some bytes
                    f.write(x)                                                           
main()
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\danger\file.py", line 20, in <module>
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\danger\file.py", line 14, in main
io.UnsupportedOperation: read
```

and after execution the file.py is 0 filled but not the .jpg files in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a file that you have opened it with `wb` mode. `wb` mode indicates that you want to write something into it.

```
import PIL.Image as Image
import io
mport os

def main():
    path = __file__ #name of file = file.py
    path = path.replace('file.py', '') # replace the name of file to get folder path
    your_path = path #path of imgs and python file
    files = os.listdir(your_path)
    keyword = "*.jpg"
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(keyword):
            jpg_path = os.path.join(your_path, file)
            if os.path.isfile(jpg_path):
                pil_im = Image.open(jpg_path)
                b = io.BytesIO()
                pil_im.save(b, 'jpeg')
                im_bytes = b.getvalue()
                # This is a bytearray of your image. Do rest of your coding...                                                           
main()
```